# Pass server control value as jquery parameter

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, servercontrols

I'm trying to take a value from a drop down list and pass the selected value as parameters in an AJAX page method call via jquery. How do I reference the control's selected value in the `data:` parameter segment of the call? Do I just reference it by it's ID? Here's what I've got:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#AssignEmployeeButton").click(function()
    {
        $.ajax(
        {
            type: "POST",
            url: "TeamManager.aspx/IsOnlyTeamEmployee",
            data: "{'employeeId': *control value here*}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(msg)
            {
                //function body will go here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `JSON.stringify` instead of trying to write json by hand.

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    data: "{'employeeId': $('#idOfYourDDL').val()}"
});
```

Comment: I had a hunch it was something like that. Thanks! :)